# How to search the content of Excel Macro in SharePoint?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, search

If I want to search the  content of  Excel Macro for an interested key word, I download the excel s/s from SharePoint and manually search each bas file in it. Is there any way I can directly search the content of the file from  SharePoint  itself?